# Type NSArray cannot be downcast implicitly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm working on converting my app over to swift but I'm running into a swift error I don't quite understand yet.

In Obj-c I have a `for in` loop here:

```
for (MYVisitor *visitor in visitors) {
    if (visitor.boxState == MYVisitorBoxStateChatting) {
        [self.chattingVisitors addObject:visitor];
    }
    else {
        [self.unknownVisitors addObject:visitor];
    }
}
```

In swift I have:

```
for visitor: MYVisitor in visitors {
        if visitor.boxState == MYVisitorBoxStateChatting {
            self.chattingVisitors.addObject(visitor)
        }
        else {
            self.unknownVisitors.addObject(visitor)
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error in swift that says: `NSArray cannot be implicitly downcast to MYVisitor, did you mean to use as to force downcast?`

Xcode recommends this change: `for visitor: FHVisitor in visitors as MYVisitor {...` 
which then gives me this error: `MYVisitor does not conform to protocol SequenceType`

Comment: Can you show how `visitor` and `visitors` are declared in your Swift code?

Comment: sure: `let visitors: NSArray= MYUser.loggedInUser().currentCompany.onlineVisitors.array`

Comment: and visitor is declared in the loop: `for visitor: MYVisitor in visitors`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `visitors` is an `NSArray` and it is *guaranteed* that all its elements are of
the `MYVisitor` type then you can cast the array to `[MYVisitor]`:

```
for visitor in visitors as [MYVisitor] {
    // ...
}
```

Note that this will crash at runtime if any array element is *not* a `MYVisitor`.

Alternatively, you can check the array with

```
if let theVisitors = visitors as? [MYVisitor] {
    for visitor in theVisitors {
        println(visitor.name)
    }
} else {
    // This is not an array of MYVisitor objects.
}
```

Or you can check each array element:

```
for item in visitors {
    if let visitor = item as? MYVisitor {
        // ...
    } else {
        // This is not a MYVisitor.
    }
}
```